# Why should I use IoC Container (Autofac, Ninject, Unity etc) for Dependency Injection in ASP.Net Applications?

Tags: c#, asp.net, dependency-injection

It is kind of theoretical question.

I am already using Unity DY with Service(Facade) pattern on Business layer.
I is pretty simple to use it but...

there is obviously performance and memory overhead in every small transaction. Instead of creation of DataContext (read it like "sql-connection") i am create several service objects by unity.

Example:
simple operation "GetAllArticles" cause creation of

Useless:

- UserService    (for permission checks)
- ArticleService (for Article Crud operation)

And usefull:

- DataContext (for the articleService)
- ArticleViewModels.

But what if is an HightLoadApplication, and billions of people over the world, trying to get article from my super site? What about garbage collector and server's cpu temperature?

So:

- Am i understand work with unity(or any other) correct?
- Is there any alternative solutions?
- what should i do in a case of highload application

I will be happy to hear your opinion and experience, even if it is not panacea or "best practice".

Comment: [you can look up](http://www.palmmedia.de/blog/2011/8/30/ioc-container-benchmark-performance-comparison) performance of various injectors and decide for yourself whether you think the performance hit will outweigh all the benefits of being able to unit test (hint: it very likely will not)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

When we write code, we aim for [SOLID Design Principals](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735683204) which make code adaptive to change.

- S : The single responsibility principle
- O : The open/closed principle
- L : The Liskov substitution principle
- I : Interface segregation
- D : Dependence injection

In order to achieve first four - SOLI, we want to inject dependencies.

> Is there any alternative solutions?

You can achieve dependency injection (DI) either manually *(Poor Man's Dependency Injection)* or using Inversion of Control (IoC) container *(like Autofac, Ninject, Structure Map, Unity and so)*.

> what should i do in a case of highload application

Using IoC container for DI is never been an issue for speed.

[Mark Seemann](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1935182501) said , *"creating an object instance is something the .Net Framework does extremely fast. any performance bottleneck your application may have will appear in other place, so don't worry about it."*

The **bottom line** is I personally use IoC container in every ASP.Net MVC and Web API projects. Besides, I hardly see any open source MVC and Web API application which does not use IoC container.

Comment: The 'D' in SOLID actually means Dependency Inversion. Dependency Injection is a way of achieving Dependency Inversion.

Answer (score 4):

For understanding how DI works, take a look at this great article: 
http://www.martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html

I also recommend reading even half of this book by Mark Seemann: 
http://www.amazon.ca/Dependency-Injection-NET-Mark-Seemann/dp/1935182501/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1454620933&sr=8-1&keywords=mark+seemann

Unless you are trying to set a performance record I do not believe DI will have a noticeable effect on performance. We have been using SimpleInjector for the past year (it is one of the fastest out there) on a website that gets several million hits per day and the performance effect is almost unmeasurable.